# EditText innner SpannableString

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring

I have use setText() to set **SpannableString** into **EditText**, but when I put selection into SpannableString content. Sadly, I found EditText will not show what I have inputed when I input something from keyboard with **the cursor in content(SpannableString)**. But if I place the selection to the real of content(SpannableString), the EditText will show that I have inputed.Please forgive my poor in english. May I should use cursor replace for selection. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem. I should use `Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE`
like this:

```
spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, matcher.start(),end,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

but I used `Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE`, the result is I can't insert text between emoji.